# Can pescetarians eat gelatin?

Tags: gelatin, pescetarianism

I'm a pescetarian, and I accidentally took a gum not knowing that there was some beef gelatin in it. Am I allowed to do that?

Comment: Up to the person I guess. My partner is pescetarian and she generally avoids things that she knows for sure contains gelatin. But I am pretty sure some of the desserts she has when eating out will have it. Its very hard to completely avoid in practise.

Comment: As a general rule, you can substitute powdered agar for gelatin in equal amounts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gelatin is not vegan, vegetarian nor pescetarian.  Gelatin is made of animal collagen.

Collagen is extracted from animals' (pigs' or cows') hides and bones through a chemical process.

I would not worry that much for such an accident.  It happens.  Being pescetarian/vegetarian/vegan is a choice, an accident does not make you less of those.

Answer (score 1):

It's up to you what you allow yourself to do and how you set your taboos. By definition, gelatin is not vegetarian, as it's made of a slaughtered animal. However, it's only a byproduct and not what the cow was actually killed for, so I can see an argument for being unbothered by it, and I won't take an issue with you eating it and still calling yourself vegetarian (or pescetarian).